# Cannot get rsync to ignore my git folder and my todo file

Tags: rsync

I'm uploading a web page to my server and I simply want the rsync to ignore 3 things: The .git/ folder, my .gitignore file and my TODO. I have tried serveral formats. My latest command being:

```
rsync -avz --include "*" --exclude .git/ --exclude .gitignore --exclude TODO --del ariela@pc01:/home/web/taskadmin /home/web/tests/
```

However the all the unwanted files are still being copied. I don't understand. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use '.git', '.gitignore' (I mean that you should use single quotes mabye?) . Did you try to put all directories in a file and use --exclude-from '/home/mydir/exclude.txt'?

Comment: I added the single quotes and it was the same result. It still copied the .git folder (and the other stuff)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All files are included by default. Simply exclude those you don't want to be copied

```
rsync -avz --exclude .git/ --exclude .gitignore --exclude TODO --del ariela@pc01:/home/web/taskadmin /home/web/tests/
```